# How to set value of dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect programmatically?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've got a CheckedMultiSelect which was created programmatically.

```
new dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect({
        id: 'products',
        name: 'products',
        multiple: true,
        readOnly: false,
        store: store,
    },'products').startup();
```

So far so good. MultiSelect is created. Now, I open webpage with multiselect, check some checkboxes and use Chrome console:

```
var productSelect = dijit.byId("products");
productSelect.get('value');
[4, 3]
```

[4, 3] is an array of checked values.

My next step is uncheck previously checked boxes and use Chrome console again:

```
productSelect.set('value', [4, 3]);
```

And this is the place where problem has occured. The function 'set' is not working. Boxes are not being selected.

I've even tried

```
productSelect.set('value', ['4', '3']);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, i found an answer [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/selects_using_stores/).

> However, dijit.form.Select possesses an important limitation: **it is
>   implemented in such a way that it does not handle non-string item
>   identities well.** Particularly, setting the current value of the widget
>   programmatically via select.set("value", id) will not work with
>   non-string (e.g. numeric) identities.

The solution is to cast ids in store to strings and use

```
productSelect.set('value', ['4', '3']);
```